# Using multi pins with Phonegap and jQuery Mobile

Tags: ajax, google-maps, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing a new app using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap.

In my case, I use the geolocalization for showing every interesting point around the users. Cordinates and data are loading by Ajax and json.

Now i try to use a gmap ([here](http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html)), but the prestations (speed loading in particular) are slow and very far from native experience.

Which is the best metod for use maps with Phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest solution I so up today is Google maps v3 API. I have used it inside several of mine apps and it works fine, of course feeling is not fully native like but you will never be able to achieve it in combination with jQuery Mobile. Framework used in that example is  Google maps v2 API and it it's deprecated last few years.

V3 API is done from the scratch so it works much faster then V2, not to mention it has a full support for HTML5 browsers.

Few working examples can be found in my other answer **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/using-google-maps-javascript-api-v3-with-jquery-mobile/)**.

You can make it even more faster if you initialize map during the application initialization. In this case map will be ready and available as soon as map page is shown. Feel free to ask if you need a help with implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I trying this example of Google Maps V3 [here](http://blog.sofasurfer.org/2011/06/27/dynamic-google-map-markers-via-simple-json-file/), and the map on Phonegap are finally fast.

I don't recommend gmap UI on Phonegap.